# Map Reduce in MongoDB: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have to use `mapReduce` for a project and I started to follow the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/).

I've created a [test project](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/mongodb-map-reduce/blob/cde57ea8d4ea72661e35319ea5fb65d5552b2e9f/server.js) following the [first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/#return-the-total-price-per-customer-id) example from the page.

I've created a database named `test` in Mongo, and I inserted the object from example in collection `col_one`:

```
{
     _id: ObjectId("50a8240b927d5d8b5891743c"),
     cust_id: "abc123",
     ord_date: new Date("Oct 04, 2012"),
     status: 'A',
     price: 250,
     items: [ { sku: "mmm", qty: 5, price: 2.5 },
              { sku: "nnn", qty: 5, price: 2.5 } ]
}
```

My code is simple (like in example):

```
// MongoDB part
// Create server

var mapFunction1 = function() {
   emit(this.cust_id, this.price);
};

var reduceFunction1 = function(keyCustId, valuesPrices) {
   return Array.sum(valuesPrices);
};

collection.mapReduce(
   mapFunction1,
   reduceFunction1,
   { out: "col_two" }
);

// Print items from col_two
```

This throws this error:

```
.../node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:524
        throw err;
              ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

If I change to this, this error disappears.

```
collection.mapReduce(
   mapFunction1,
   reduceFunction1,
   { out: "col_two" },
   function() {
       // Print items from col_two
   }
);
```

Why does the error disappear?

Comment: Because the callback is a required parameter of `mapReduce`.  See [docs](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#mapreduce).

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Why didn't they use [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/#return-the-total-price-per-customer-id) the callback?

Comment: Because that example is using the shell which is a synchronous interface.

Comment: Tested it. It's true. If you add a great answer, I am glad to mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're hitting is one of the key differences between the API used in the shell and the native node.js driver:  the shell is synchronous while the node.js driver is asynchronous.

Because the node.js driver is asynchronous, you must supply a callback parameter to the `mapReduce` call as indicated in the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#mapreduce) so that you can receive the result.